# Why does my sorted array occasionally return random 0s at the end?

Tags: objective-c

I wrote a program to sort a randomly generated array of 50 integers from greatest to least. So far it works, but it will occasionally return random zeros at the end of the sorted array. These zeros are not present in the unsorted array, and they do not always appear. Here's my program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Number: NSObject

- (void) start;
- (int) getValue;
- (void) counted;
- (void) placeValue: (int) a;

@end

@implementation Number
{
    int x;
}

- (void) start
{
    x = arc4random_uniform(1000);
    if (x == 1)
    {
        x = x+1;
    }
}

- (int) getValue
{
    return x;
}

- (void) counted
{
    x = 0;
}

- (void) placeValue: (int) a
{
    x = a;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSMutableArray *unsortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 50];

        for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
        {
            Number *num = [[Number alloc] init];
            [num start];
            [unsortedArray addObject: num];
        }

        for  (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
        {
            printf("%i, ", [unsortedArray[n] getValue]);
        }
        printf ("unsorted array.\n\n");

        int x = 0;
        int y = 1001;

        for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < 50; m++)
            {
                if (([unsortedArray[m] getValue] > x) && ([unsortedArray[m] getValue] < y))
                {
                    x = [unsortedArray[m] getValue];
                }
            }

            printf("%i, ", x);
            y = x;
            x = 0;
        }

        printf("sorted array.\n");
    } return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say the array is randomly generated? Are zeros allowed?

Comment: arc4random_uniform does return 0 value :  [see](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)start
{
    x = (arc4random_uniform(1000) + 1);
}
```

You don't want to only be increasing x when you hit 0 or 1, since that will skew the results. arc4random_uniform will return a random number less than 1000 in this case, so 0 -> 999, adding 1 to all values, gives you 1 -> 1000. Adjust your numbers to suit what you need.

There are other issues in your code though. Why create your own Number class? Why create your own sort method? Use NSNumber and NSArray's sort methods.

Here is a much cleaner version:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSMutableArray* unsortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];

        for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; ++n) {
            [unsortedArray addObject:@(arc4random_uniform(999) + 1)];
        }

        for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; ++n) {
            printf("%li, ", (long)[unsortedArray[n] integerValue]);
        }
        printf ("unsorted array.\n\n");

        NSArray* sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            return [obj2 compare:obj1];
        }];

        for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < 50; ++n) {
            printf("%li, ", (long)[sortedArray[n] integerValue]);
        }
        printf("sorted array.\n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! Now I just have to wrap my head around the whole sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult thing. (Please excuse my noobity.) :D

Comment: `sortedArrayUsingComparator` is just one of the ways to sort an array. All you have to do is decide the order of the two objects passed in. In this case, we're letting the `compare:` method determine that result. Doing `[obj2 compare:obj1]` gives you an array in reverse order (normally it would be `[obj1 compare:obj2]`).

Comment: Also, if this answer helped, please don't forget to up vote it and select it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to do that at first... :P

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) start
{
    x = arc4random_uniform(1000);
    if (x == 0)
      x = x + 1;
}
```

Comment: I tried entering that in my code, but the sorted array will still return random zeros at the end of it. Even when the original array has no zeros, the sorted array will still randomly return zeros at the end of it. Here is an example of what the program returns:

Comment: 148, 234, 856, 382, 644, 571, 289, 887, 270, 54, 876, 123, 443, 399, 299, 17, 957, 545, 614, 128, 785, 856, 336, 754, 782, 232, 951, 365, 205, 1, 416, 335, 756, 170, 381, 11, 258, 454, 700, 171, 913, 893, 926, 696, 273, 864, 251, 327, 170, 312, unsorted array.

957, 951, 926, 913, 893, 887, 876, 864, 856, 785, 782, 756, 754, 700, 696, 644, 614, 571, 545, 454, 443, 416, 399, 382, 381, 365, 336, 335, 327, 312, 299, 289, 273, 270, 258, 251, 234, 232, 205, 171, 170, 148, 128, 123, 54, 17, 11, 1, 0, 0, sorted array.
Program ended with exit code: 0

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is focusing on the fact that `arc4random_uniform` can generate zero as an acceptable value (which is true), but there is another problem: Your sort algorithm is incorrect, as it will only work if the values in the array are unique. But, if you have any duplicate values (and there's no assurances that `arc4random_uniform` won't generate some duplicates), your algorithm will show only one of those values, and thus, by the time you get to the end, you'll see a bunch of extra zeros.

There are tons of different [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), but it's probably easier to just avail yourself of one of the native `NSMutableArray` sort methods, which gets you out of the weeds of writing your own.